# SecItemCopyMatching is returning nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

I have this method

```
- (NSString *)bundleSeedID:(NSError **)error __attribute__((annotate("oclint:suppress"))) {
NSDictionary *query = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                       (__bridge NSString *)kSecClassGenericPassword, (__bridge NSString *)kSecClass,
                       BUNDLE_SEED_ID, kSecAttrAccount,
                       EMPTY_STRING, kSecAttrService,
                       (__bridge NSString *)kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly, (__bridge NSString *)kSecAttrAccessible,
                       (id)kCFBooleanTrue, kSecReturnAttributes,
                       nil];
CFDictionaryRef result = nil;
OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFTypeRef *)&result);
if (status == errSecItemNotFound) {
    status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)query, (CFTypeRef *)&result);
}

if (status != errSecSuccess) {
    if (error) *error = [ErrorUtils bundleSeedErrorWithCode:(int)status];
    return nil;
}
NSString *accessGroup = [(__bridge NSDictionary *)result objectForKey:(__bridge NSString *)kSecAttrAccessGroup];
NSArray *components = [accessGroup componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSString *bundleSeedID = [[components objectEnumerator] nextObject];
CFRelease(result);
return bundleSeedID;
}
```

and I don't understand why sometimes *result* is null.

**Note: This code is always being executed in main thread without any asynchronous call**

Can you please help me understand why is this happening? This code is only executed when I open the app.

I know I could check if *result* is null and then I won't *CFRelease(result);* but it's not expected to happen this. Once the app crashes, if I open it again, everything is ok.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You are very likely launching in the background when the device is locked. While the device is locked, you don't have access to certain protected data in the keychain; you should see this in the error message.

You do appear to be passing `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly` to the creation, it's possible that you added `kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly` to your app after creating the keychain items (or that you don't pass this during creation elsewhere).

Your code checks for `errSecItemNotFound`, but you should be checking for `errSecDataNotAvailable` if I recall correctly to detect this problem. (You can also check UIApplication's `isProtectedDataAvailable.) You shouldn't try to create an item in that case of course; you just need an elegant way to fail.

It's fairly rare to be launched before first unlock, but that's also possible, and the keychain won't be available. Pending Bluetooth connections, for example, can cause this as I recall. I don't believe that push notifications can launch the app in that state, but it's possible.

In any case, you need to be checking for unexpected errors and handling a `nil` value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rob. But even if I remove kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly, I still getting result == null. Is there any reason for that?

Comment: That wouldn't make it better; that would make it worse for the case I'm describing. kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly is only relevant when you *create* the item. It sets the protection level.

Comment: Also the "ThisDeviceOnly" is important. If a user syncs their keychain to another device (particularly if they buy a new phone), the item won't be copied.